# leer columna de dataset con pandas en jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, dataset

Quisiera saber ¿Por qué no puedo hacer un `describe` en la columna 'inj_diff '?

Me sale error, pero al hacer un describe de toda la tabla si me sale normal, quisiera leer solo esa columna ya que es la columna `target`; al hacer el `describe` de cualquier otra columna si sale. por favor si me pueden ayudar.

[image: Foto de columnas.]

En la foto pueden ver que se pude leer el archivo `CSV` y todas sus columnas pero al leer la columna en mención me sale error.

Comment: Buen día, revisa si el nombre de la columna es correcto, en la imagen parece ser que es un espacio y veo que también lo utilizas al intentar obtener la descripción de la columna pero podría ser que haya mas espacios en blanco o algún otro caracter especial. Por cierto, es mucho mejor que incluyas toda la información como texto y no como imagen para que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Muchas gracias @HeytalePazguato, ya encontré la solución, la variable en mención tiene caracteres al final tal que así 'inj_diff\xa0'

Answer (score 0):

El log de errores parece imcompleto. Ya sea que el error pueda venir de alguno de los valores de la columna (cosa que se podria confirmar con el resto del log) o quiza podria ser por el espacio en blanco del nombre de la columna. Podrias intentar quitando el espacio al final de 'inj_diff '?

Comment: Muchas gracias @pythonista_entusiasta ya encontré la solución, la variable en mención tiene caracteres al final tal que así 'inj_diff\xa0'